# Display who created a file in explorer

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-search

I would like a column for 'who created' a document to be visible in windows explorer.

Typically I would achieve this by right clicking on the column titles, (selecting "more") and selecting "Authors" to display the author of the file.
However unlike Word and Excel documents which save author info automatically (on our system, at least), Solidworks files do not. If I look in the file properties, there is no useful info to be gleaned:[image: Example file properties]

There is one place where the information appears to be availible though; if I select "Security", I can see the name of the file creator listed 2nd from the top in the "Group or user names" field. Is there any way I can access this information to display it/ filter by it in Windows explorer? [image: Security image]

*PS Sorry for the gratuitous blurring*

Comment: You can add the `Owner` column by right clicking and adding the column.

Comment: @Ramhound That'll do it, I had assumed the document `Properties` window would be exaustive, and if any properties were missing in that then it meant they didn't exist. Clearly that isn't true, so is there a way to view *all* of a file's properties at the same time (such as `Owner`), so that I don't make this mistake again? Anyway, post so I can accept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to view all of a file's properties (such as Owner) to
>   the explorer window?

Just add the desired column to your explorer window.

[image]

If the desired property isn't already listed just click `More...`

Comment: Actually, I meant to have them all in one place. Exactly like the `Right Click`->`Properties`->`Details` window, except with all of the document properties, not just a select few.

Comment: You won't be able to display *all* the document properties.  What properties can be displayed depends on numerous factors, in a default configuration of Windows, some of the date properties cannot be displayed.  Additionally, most of the properties you can display, are based on what applications are installed on your system.

Comment: Well maybe not all the properties, just the non-empty ones. There may be some programattic way, I can think of how to do it with a VBScript but was hoping for something built-in. I'll possibly ask this as a separate question as I don't think this conversation belongs here, unless you can think of a way of displaying them natively?

Comment: What you want won't be possible with VBScript.  If my answer does not actually answer the question you shouldn't accept it.  [Custom folder field for windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942112/custom-folder-field-for-windows-7)

Comment: It answers it perfectly, I was just interested to know more, but can see that it was not within the question scope, so I have asked it [elsewhere](https://superuser.com/q/1218523/705597).

Answer (score 0):

You could add the `Owner` column to the list of displayed columns. Beware though, that this is the operating system user, and the info is saved not in the file itself, but in the file system metadata. So if you (for example) upload the file to a web server and then get it via HTTP, in that case this info won't be preserved. Might be useful in a multi-user Windows domain environment, though.

Comment: I posted this as a separate answer, because the accepted answer does not explain the difference between `Authors` and `Owner` columns. The `Authors` column is taken from the file itself. But not all files contain such info, and those which do contain it are not necessarily supported by Windows.