# Display all file properties in windows explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-search

With a file in Windows explorer I can <kbd>right-click</kbd>  `Properties` `[Details] tab` to display a number of file properties.

However, that list of properties (*name, date created, author* etc.) is only a very small subset of the properties that are accessible via

`[View] tab`  `Add columns`  `Choose columns`

Is there a way I can view all of the additional properties that are missing from the `Property [Details]tab` window (or at least all of the non-empty ones), either:

- Through the property window itself (by adding more fields)
- Through some other windows explorer native menu

or

- Through another means like a script with a popup window (less preferred)

but

- **Not** by simply using `Choose columns` to add them directly to the explorer pane

I would find this useful as with a quick glance over a file's properties you would be able to decide which fields contain particularly interesting data to add to the main explorer pane as new filter columns.

Comment: No. The extra details are dependent on the 1/ the file type and 2/ the program used to create the file.

Answer (score 1):

**FileMeta** for you. You'll love it.

[Link to old project page at codeplex.com](https://filemeta.codeplex.com/)

[Link to new project page at github.com](https://github.com/Dijji/FileMeta)

Comment: It is more preferable to include essential parts of of your post then refer to link :)

Comment: I thought he would read the manual (documentation) from the link that I gave. And he (or anyone else) should also refer to it (link) if they've really interesting.

Comment: Yeah, and that's the problem with what are effectively link-only answers: Not a year later codeplex seems to be shutting down, project moved to github. I added the link to github, but you should consider at least explaining what FileMeta does. So, even if github should die someday, we will know there _was_ a solution, sometime.