# (How) Can one set arbitrary file/directory properties for Windows File Explorer?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-explorer, filesystems

I would like to enforce a *genuine* custom ordering on certain files and especially directories when looking at them via File Explorer. I don't want to resort to tricks like pre-pending '_' or other characters to the item's name then sorting by name.

I've found you can view a ton of different property columns, by going to File Explorer's "View" tab, then "add columns". Some of the hundreds of options are "Priority", "Tags" and "#".
If I were able set any of those and then sort them asc./desc., that would solve my use case.

But there doesn't seem to be any obvious way to set them... I'd be perfectly willing to jump into a (PowerShell) terminal to achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

I've found what at first seemed like a promising tool (via [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1218523/display-all-file-properties-in-windows-explorer)):
[FileMeta](https://github.com/Dijji/FileMeta)

unfortunately my prelimary fiddling reveiled that it can hardly be called a solution:

- It's old / no longer maintained (last update 2017)
- Bad UI (no search or "jump to letter" for properties)
- And last but not least: *it doesn't work for directories*.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer to your dilemma.